# How to get full explanation of Elasticsearch query Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm currecntly trying to test out some new score functions on my Elasticsearch query but I'm not yielding the results I am expecting.

I found this on their site about explaining queries [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)

I can run as a curl command but does anyone know how to translate this to use the Java api?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search.html
client.prepareSearch() and QueryBuilders are pretty much the bread and butter of the Java API.  The nesting of method calls is also pretty much the same as the nesting in a JSON query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the ES5 Java API, you can get the explanation like this:

```
QueryBuilder query = matchAllQuery(); // your query

ExplainRequest request = new ExplainRequest("index", "type", "id").query(query);
ExplainResponse explainResponse = client.explain(request).actionGet();
Explanation explanation = explainResponse.getExplanation();
```

Where `client` is your `org.elasticsearch.client.Client` instance.